# How to get the default alpha rule of graphics object?

Tags: java, graphics

In case the alpha rule is not set with a specific rule `setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src)`. How to know which rule has been applied to draw image on the graphics object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `Graphics g;` object then you can do:

```
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Composite composite = g2d.getComposite();
```